# Configuring ufw and iPredator VPN

Tags: vpn, firewall, openvpn, ufw

I am running a VPN via IPredator on Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop, which works perfectly, when ufw is disabled.

When I enable ufw, I logically cannot establish a connection. IPredator states that I have to meet the following IP-range to get things working:

```
First IP address: 46.246.32.0
Last IP address: 46.246.63.255
Net mask: 255.255.224.0
```

I already did a basic ufw configuration, following this [tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity/Firewall):

```
25005/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
25005/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
25005/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25005/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

25,53,80,110,443/tcp       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
53,67,68/udp               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
51413/tcp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
51413/udp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
6969/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
25,53,80,110,443/tcp       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
53,67,68/udp               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
51413/tcp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
51413/udp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
6969/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

How can I configure the mentioned IP-range in ufw?